# rails flash notice not working with remote => true

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tabs

I have three tabs on one view page. One of the tabs is a form to update user account. Since this page uses jquery, whenever I refresh the page, it goes back to the first active tab instead of the current tab. I fixed this by adding `:remote=> true` to this line of code `<%= semantic_form_for @user, :remote => true do |f| %>`. This updates the form without going back to the first active tab.

The problem is I have a flash notice that is not showing up. If I remove the `:remote => true` then it works fine, but it brings me back to the main active tab.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

JS to switch tabs here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.tabs a').click(function(){
    switch_tabs($(this));
});

switch_tabs($('.active'));

});

function switch_tabs(obj)
{
$('.tab-content').hide();
$('.tabs a').removeClass("active");
var id = obj.attr("rel");

$('#'+id).show();
obj.addClass("active");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you render in your update action

Answer (score 0):

Well you have 2 separate issues here:

- you JS code does switching on a click event. When your page loads first, there are no clicks so it won't change tabs. You need to indicate somehow which tab is active. I usually do it on the server side by adding `active` class to the HTML element and then use CSS to highlight/choose it.
- `remote=>true` will execute ajax call which will return you something back. Typically the xml or json is returned and not HTML. I think in your case you are returning HTML that will contain flash message but your browser won't show it since your page is not refreshed.

Comment: how do i make it so when the form submit it submits back to the same tab?